# Painting on JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, paint

I got 4 panels in a Frame.

North, East, Center and South.

How can I paint on just 1 specific JPanel inside a Frame?

I tried painting but it seems that I am painting in the JFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create new panel and put it in the center, then override its paintComponent method.
see [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) and also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html)